# Virtual Folder defined for a language site not working with Data API URL

Tags: content-search, solr, multilingual

We are on multi-lingual websites having en-CA and fr-CA languages as well. We defined virtual folder for fr-CA to share the same domain name with en-CA. Hence the en-CA works on `www.mywebsite.ca` and fr-Ca works on `www.mywebsite.ca/cafr`, all the pages are coming up fine with correct context language.

Having Solr as search engine,  for search listing pages we are using Data API Services having data-api-url like   “dataservices/pagename”, which is working fine for all the languages but fr-CA. Reason being when it comes to fr-CA the data api url is not respecting the Virtual Folder as part of the URL and returning en-CA search results.

**What I have tried:**

I tried adding /cafr to the data api url especially when the current context language is fr-CA but it throws a 404.

How can I force Data API to get the search results in fr-CA by passing the Virtual Folder value?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is"dataservices" registered as a web API route ?

Comment: @VincentLui - thank you for the comment. Yes, they are registered as a web API route in global.asax..

Comment: Can you please try adding querystring parameter sc_lang=fr-CA and see if that works ? Eg. dataservices/pagename?sc_lang=fr-CA

Comment: Tried adding the query string but no luck, do I need to add the virtual folder value which is /cafr in the data-api url?

Comment: Can you add some code samples of how you are 1) setting the context language for inbound requests and 2) how you are registering your `dataservices` route?

Comment: Web API routes should be registered in the initialize pipeline, not global.asax. Not sure if it'll make any difference in this case however, it's more just the correct convention.

Comment: Any updates @RathanM ?

Comment: @VincentLui - After doing some research we figured out that we need to register an other route within the global.asax file which looks something like this path "dataservices/cafr/pagename". By doing this the URL is respecting the virtual folder setting and we were able to achieve the requirement.